# How do I undo a expo project that I build locally using npx expo run:android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

How do I remove the local build that I accidentally created using npx expo run:android?

So I accidentally ran a npx expo run:android in my project which created a local build. However, I am perfectly happy with using the development server and bundling my project everytime. Since the local build is taking up a lot of space how do I revert back? I want to remove everything related to the local build and just use the development server.

Comment: Just delete the built Android app from your source code and run "expo start -a"